# Check if a transformation $L: u \rightarrow (u(2),u'(2))$ is linear.Find all solutions for this equation: $L(u)=(3,-2)$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Check if a transformation defined like this $L: u \rightarrow (u(2),u'(2))$ is an linear operator where $L:\mathbb{R[x]} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^2}$. Note that $\mathbb{R[x]}$ is a vector space of real polynomials.
After that find all solutions for the given equation: $L(u)=(3,-2)$.

The first part of this example is easy but how can I find all the solution for this equation? When I try to solve this equation I get the following system of two equations:

$a_0+2a_1+4a_2 + ... +a_n2^n+... = 3$

$0 +a_1+4a_2 + ... +na_n2^{n-1}+... = -2$

Comment: If the first part was so easy, can you tell us what answer you got?

Comment: @JohnHughes If a poster presents a problem with two parts, says they had no problem doing the first part, says they are stuck on the second and gives partial work, I think they are doing fine. I do not understand your comment seemingly demanding work on the first part. If it was meant in a 'what have you done' manner I think the practice has been misapplied here.

Comment: Suppose that the answer to the first part was the wrong one ... that might partly explain why the poster was having trouble on the second part. I wasn't asking for OP's work -- just the answer. I suppose it's a matter of taste, but I find students are sometimes confident that they know something, but what they "know" is completely wrong. A little probing often helps. And if OP is going to ask more questions, disclosing/demonstrating current understanding is probably a good habit to get into. On re-reading, though, I see that my question might appear contentious, and I'm sorry for that.

Comment: @JohnHughes No problem, thanks for responding. I think this quick exchange is good, though. You and I both want to demonstrate that those of us looking for additional information from posters aren't doing so in an unthoughtful way.

Comment: Agree completely. And thanks for questioning me on this -- I'll have to be more careful with my phrasing, and it's easy to forget that.

Answer (score 1):

The basic theory of linear equations is at play here: all you need to do is to find the kernel of $L$, and a single solution, and the rest of the solutions lie in the same coset as the solution you found.

So let's work on the kernel first. If $L(p(x))=(0,0)$, that means that $2$ is a root of both $u$ and $u'$. You've probably seen the proof (or maybe not) that when $u$ and $u'$ share a root, that means it had multiplicity greater than $1$ in $u$'s factorization. That is, $(x-2)^2|u(x)$. Clearly then, any polynomial divisible by $(x-2)^2$ is in the kernel of $L$. Let's call the set of these polynomials $V$. They are a subspace of $\mathbb R[x]$, and moreover it is a subspace of index $2$.

Now, it is easy to see that $L$ is onto $\mathbb R\times \mathbb R$. Obviously $L(b(x-2)+a)=(a,b)$ for any $a,b\in\mathbb R$. This means the kernel of $L$ has index $2$ as well, and that $V$ is precisely the kernel of $L$. And here we also scoop up our "one solution" to our original problem: $L(-2(x-2)+3)=(3,-2)$.

So the complete set of solutions is everything in the coset

$$
-2(x-2)+3+(x-2)^2\mathbb R[x]
$$